# tutorial usercontrol with flipview/carousel on a timer XAML WinRT apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I love the new IHeartRadio app for Windows 10, and would like to be able to reproduce their carousel on the sign up page.  I think it could make an awsome tutorial usercontrol for my apps.  However I have no idea who to reproduce this?

Are they using a flipview with a timer? are they using a XAML Carousel? do they have a background image with animation on it?  Any help, idea would be great!

Edit: here is a video of the animation i would like to reproduce: http://www.dailymotion.com/video/k5ccgTM1k8BJvRd6IOn

[image]

Comment: I haven't bothered with upgrading to win10 yet, or use iheartradio, do you have like a video/gif or something to show the UX? I'm sure it can be reproduced.

Comment: I have updated my question: here is the link: http://www.dailymotion.com/video/k5ccgTM1k8BJvRd6IOn

Comment: It's not a FlipView control, it's a custom control they built I believe. There's no built-in Carousel control either (except the one called CarouselPanel that only can be used inside ComboBox). And yes, you need a Timer for that opacity animation. So I guess you will have to build your own control for this.

Answer (score 0):

You would not need a custom control for this. The desired UX can be achieved by styling the Windows 10 Pivot control. A timer can be added for changing the selected index and executing corresponding animations.